# Python: How do I make each part of the array only one digit long?

Tags: python, arrays

my code is supposed to make sure (for this section) that each inputted number is an integer and is only one digit long, however I am not sure how to make sure that each number is only one digit while it is in an array.

```
amount = 0
code = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
code[amount] = int(input("enter the first number"))
amount = amount + 1
while amount < 7 and amount != 0:
    code[amount] = int(input("please enter the next number"))
    amount = amount + 1
amount = 0
if len(code[amount])>1:
    print("you have entered a number that is more than one digit")
elif len(code[amount])==1:
    print("")
else:
    print("invalid input")
```

my expected result would be an error when you enter any number that is longer than one digit, however this error is returned instead.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\task 1 full code.py", line 9, in <module>
    if len(code[amount])>1:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: Compare it with `0 <= code[amount] <= 9`...

Comment: `code[amount]` has  type integer `code` is of type list hence you are getting above error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check at input time (and loop to repeat the input until the value is okay):

```
while amount < 7 and amount != 0:
    while True:  # until a valid digit is given
        code[amount] = int(raw_input("please enter the next number"))
        if 0 <= code[amount] <= 9:
            break
        print "Please enter only single digits!"
    amount = amount + 1
```

Or you can check later:

```
if not all(0 <= c <= 9 for c in code):
    print "Not all values are only digits!"
```